# Let $f:R^k \to R, k \geq 2$ Partial function, continuous in punctured neighborhood of $a \in R^k$ Prove $f$ Is not one-to-one

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$k \geq 1, f:R^k \to R$ Partial function that is continuous in punctured neighborhood of $a \in R^k$, prove $f$ is not one-to-one.

---

I dont understand why $f$ Can’t be one to one, if lets say $k=2$, and $(x,y) \in R^2$ I can take a function like $(x,y) \to x*10+y$ And it seems one to one.

Can someone give me a direction?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, your function $f$ is not one-to-one, because it is not injective. I assume you choose $a=0$ so for an abiatary small open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ we can still find $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in U$ with $(x_1,y_1)=(\tfrac{\delta}{10},0)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(0,\delta)$ for $delta>0$ small enough. So our function $f$ givs us now $\delta=f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$. So it is not injective.

Now in generell. Let $p_1,p_2\in U\subset \mathbb R^2$ with $U$ open und $f:U\to \mathbb R$ continuous. We can find some $b,c\in\mathbb R$ with $f(p_1)=b$ and $f(p_2)=c$. Now you could think about that we have for every $V\subset U$ with $p_1,p_2\in V$:
$$[f(p_1),f(p_2)]=[b,c]\subset f(V)$$
If we now take two different cruves $C_1,C_2\subset U$ with $C_1\cap C_2=\{p_1,p_2\}$ (and since $U$ is open there are such curves), we have:
$$[b,c]\subset f(C_1)\cap f(C_2)$$
It follows now that:
$$f(C_1\cap C_2)=\{b,c\}\not=f(C_1)\cap f(C_2)$$
So f can't be injectiv. (Because the last equation would be hold for every injective function).